# Canvas set left, top, translate and rotate bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, drawbitmap

I want to set left and top `Bitmap` coordinates then apply Y translation and rotation on this `Bitmap` but I can't... the result is not what I expected.

Here my code :

```
point[0] = centerX-bitmapWidth/2;
point[1] = centerY;
point[2] = centerX+bitmapWidth/2;
point[3] = centerY;

rotateMat = new Matrix();
rotateMat.setTranslate(0, translationY);
rotateMat.setRotate(angle, centerX, centerY);
rotateMat.mapPoints(point);

canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, rotateMat, paint);
```

Could you help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is too vague, please elaborate it

Comment: setRotate clears your setTranlate() setting, use preTranslate/preRotate or postTranslate/postRotate